# Unable to add async / await and then unable to export variable. Any help appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, async-await

***Background***: Been trying for the last 2 day to resolve this myself by looking at various examples from both this website and others and I'm still not getting it. Whenever I try adding callbacks or async/await I'm getting no where. **I know this is where my problem is but I can't resolve it myself.**

I'm not from a programming background :( Im sure its a quick fix for the average programmer, I am well below that level.

**When I console.log(final) within the 'ready' block it works as it should, when I escape that block the output is 'undefined' if console.log(final) -or- Get req/server info, if I use console.log(ready)**

```
const request = require('request');

const ready =
// I know 'request' is deprecated, but given my struggle with async/await (+ callbacks) in general, when I tried switching to axios I found it more confusing.

request({url: 'https://www.website.com', json: true}, function(err, res, returnedData) {
    if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

var filter = returnedData.result.map(entry => entry.instrument_name);
var str = filter.toString();
var addToStr = str.split(",").map(function(a) { return `"trades.` + a + `.raw", `; }).join("");
var neater = addToStr.substr(0, addToStr.length-2);
var final = "[" + neater + "]";


//  * * * Below works here but not outside this block* * *
// console.log(final);


});

// console.log(final);
// returns 'final is not defined'

console.log(ready);
// returns server info of GET req endpoint. This is as it is returning before actually returning the data. Not done as async.

module.exports = ready;
```

Below is an short example of the JSON that is returned by website.com. The actual call has 200+ 'result' objects.

**What Im ultimately trying to achieve is**

1) return all values of "instrument_name"

2) perform some manipulations (adding 'trades.' to the beginning of each value and '.raw' to the end of each value.

3) place these manipulations into an array.
      ["trades.BTC-26JUN20-8000-C.raw","trades.BTC-25SEP20-8000-C.raw"]

4) export/send this array to another file.

5) The array will be used as part of another request used in a websocket connection. The array cannot be hardcoded into this new request as the values of the array change daily.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "kind": "option",
      "is_active": true,
      "instrument_name": "26JUN20-8000-C",
      "expiration_timestamp": 1593158400000,
      "creation_timestamp": 1575305837000,
      "contract_size": 1,
    },
    {
      "kind": "option",
      "is_active": true,
      "instrument_name": "25SEP20-8000-C",
      "expiration_timestamp": 1601020800000,
      "creation_timestamp": 1569484801000,
      "contract_size": 1,
    }
  ],
  "usIn": 1591185090022084,
  "usOut": 1591185090025382,
  "usDiff": 3298,
  "testnet": true
}
```

Comment: The second `console.log(final)` is undefined because it is called out of scope. `final` was defined within the *ready* variable. It is known only within there, the outside world has no idea it exists. Also, request is a pending promise. You would have to do your logic in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code we find two problems related to `final` and `ready` variables. The first one is that you're trying to `console.log(final)` [out of its scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

The second problem is that request doesn't immediately return the result of your API request. The reason is pretty simple, you're doing an asynchronous operation, and the result will only be returned by your callback. Your `ready` variable is just the reference to your request object.

I'm not sure about what is the context of your code and why you want to `module.exports` ready variable, but I suppose you want to export the result. If that's the case, I suggest you to return an async function which returns the response data instead of your request variable. This way you can control how to handle your response outside the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integrated `fetch` api instead of the deprecated `request`. I changed your code so that your component exports an asynchronous function called `fetchData`, which you can import somewhere and execute. It will return the result, updated with your logic:

```
module.exports = {
  fetchData: async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const returnedData = await fetch({
        url: "https://www.website.com/",
        json: true
      });

      var ready = returnedData.result.map(entry => entry.instrument_name);
      var str = filter.toString();
      var addToStr = str
        .split(",")
        .map(function(a) {
          return `"trades.` + a + `.raw", `;
        })
        .join("");
      var neater = addToStr.substr(0, addToStr.length - 2);

      return "[" + neater + "]";
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  } 
}
```

I hope this helps, otherwise please share more of your code. Much depends on where you want to display the fetched data. Also, how you take care of the *loading* and *error* states.

EDIT:
I can't get responses from this website, because you need an account as well as credentials for the api. Judging your code and your questions:

> 1) return all values of "instrument_name"

Your `map` function works:

```
var filter = returnedData.result.map(entry => entry.instrument_name);
```

> 2)perform some manipulations (adding 'trades.' to the beginning of each value and '.raw' to the end of each value.
>
> 3) place these manipulations into an array. ["trades.BTC-26JUN20-8000-C.raw","trades.BTC-25SEP20-8000-C.raw"]

This can be done using this function

```
const manipulatedData = filter.map(val => `trades.${val}.raw`);
```

You can now use `manipulatedData` in your next request. Being able to export this variable, depends on the component you use it in. To be honest, it sounds easier to me not to split this logic into two separate components - regarding the websocket -.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have updated the url so you have something that is actually usable. I have also updated the 'What Im ultimately trying to achieve is' section. 
2 side notes 1) the var ready is not called in your example (I believe it should be 'filter' based upon the following line 2) I wasn't able to console log the anything. 
Once again I really appreciate the help you are providing! :)

Comment: Thanks again! I'm 99% sure you can still call the api without an account/credentials. I was using it with a online json viewer the other day without issues. To avoid cluttering the question here is how the array would be used pastebin.com/b4f29QfG